# Actual eletronic games (as in, games played using electrons)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

What games could be played using electrons directly?

One possibility I imagine is "quantum football", with the electron trapped in a square potential well. The two players each manipulate some modes of potential fields in the well, and each has a limited budget of "observing the electron in the opponent's range". At any time the players can use an observation, and if the observation is TRUE, scores one point.

Comment: As much as I find the setting of this question funny, I fear it won't be well received. I know of instances where game-like settings are used to formulate phyisical problems, for example uncertainty relations in quantum mechanics can be formulated as bounding the probability of one player to win a game in which he has to guess the result of the measurement another player performs. I don't think this is what your question is about though.

Comment: @user2723984 Your fear was justified. Someone decided to close it all together. I for myself think answers to this question could be an excellent ressource for science teachers.

Comment: You may like Greg Egan's [quantum soccer](https://www.gregegan.net/BORDER/Soccer/Soccer.html), which he created for his short story, [Border Guards](https://www.gregegan.net/BORDER/Border.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quantum mechanical sink the battle ship, using photon canons**

As a child I played a game called ["Battelship"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game)). You placed multiple different ships on a integer grid and the other guy had to call where he wants to shoot. For example $B5$ or $C6$.

One could implement this game with electrons in a square well using different cyanin dyes. Each cyanin dye has a different excitation wavelength for it's HOMO-LUMO electron transistion. One could mix together multiple dyes, each dye corresponds to a battelship. The other player calls his shot by saying which wavelength intervall he want's to scan with his spectrometer - Or should I say shoot with his photon canon?

**Basic theory behind the game**

While the game itself proabably is going to be quite boring we can learn a few interesting things about quantum mechanics and spectroscopy by playing it!

- **Simple model for spectroscopy of cyanin**

  The general form of a cyanin molecule can be seen in figure 1. Bigger
  $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ corresponds to longer
        cyanin molceules and different colours. So there are $j=k+2$
        conjugated double bounds in $k$-cyanin. In this experiment we excite
        cyanin with light in the visible spectrum. In this energy regime the
        $\pi$-electrons belonging to the $j$ conjugated bounds are able to
        transition in higher energy levels. The $\pi$-electrons are mostly
        delocalized inside the range with length $L$, stretching from the
        right to the left nitrogen atom. Inside this range the effective
        potential for the $\pi$-electrons is mostly zero, outside it becomes
        very large. See figure 2.

  [image]

<sup>*Structure of k-cyanine, figure 1.*</sup>

[image]

<sup>*Effective potential for $\pi$-electrons in cyanin, figure 2.*</sup>

- **Energy levels and wave functions of the infinte square
        well**

  We try to approximate the energy levels of the $\pi$-electrons
        by assuming that the potential has mostly a infinite square well
        form. The solution of the Schrödinger equation for this potential is
        [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box) and can be given in closed form. The eigenenergies are
        \begin{equation}
            E_n=\frac{h^2}{8mL^2}n^2 \end{equation} and the corresponding eigenfunctions  \begin{equation}
            \psi_n=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) \end{equation}
- **HOMO state in k-cyanin**

  We assume that
        Fermi-Dirac-statistics for low temperature are applicable, so that
        all energy levels are filled by the $\pi$-electrons from the ground
        up. This way we expect the highest occupied molecular orbit (HOMO)
        to have an eigenenergy of  \begin{equation}
            \frac{h^2}{8mL^2}(k+3)^2 \end{equation} Notice that besides the $j=k+2$ $\pi$-electrons we also take the lone electron
  pair of    the
        nitrogen into account, so that the highest energy level is
        $E_{j+1}$.
- **Length of k-cyanin**

  For the length $L$ of the
        square well, as discussed before, we consider the distance between
        the two nitrogen atoms. This leads to \begin{equation}
            L(k)=(2j+2)d=(2k+4)d \end{equation} Where we assume that the $\pi$-electron system extends about one bond length over the
        conjugated chain and the average bond length is
        $d=144\textrm{pm}$.
- **HOMO-LUMO Transistion**

  The most probable transistion is the first order transition of the
  HOMO
        state into the lowest unoccupied orbital (LUMO). This is the energy
        gap we focus on in this experiment. In our model it is given by
        \begin{align}
            \Delta E(k) &=\frac{h^2}{8mL(k)^2}(n_\textrm{LUMO}^2-n_\textrm{HOMO}^2)\\&=\frac{h^2}{8mL(k)^2}((k+4)^2-(k+3)^2)
        \end{align}
- **Expected absorption spectra**

  We will radiate
        different frequencies of light onto the different cyanin samples ($k
        \in \mathbb{N}$) during the experiment. We expect the samples at
        most frequencies to transmit almost all light. So that the ratio
        between the intensity of the transmitted light $I$ and the initial
        light $I_0$ is close to one, and the so called optical density
        \begin{equation}
            OD(\nu)=\log_{10}\left(\frac{I_0(\nu)}{I(\nu)}\right) \end{equation} close to zero. At the special transition frequency
        corresponding to $\Delta E(k)$ we expect absorption of photons and
        therefore a decrease in transmitted intensity and increase of
        optical density. Our expectations are summarized in figure
        3.

[image]

$\quad\quad$ <sup>*Schematic  representation  of  the absorption band, figure 3.*</sup>

I [credit](http://www.ipc.kit.edu/download/A50_20200218.en.pdf) the Karlsruher Institute of Technology for all images used in this answer. If there is copyright concern I will remove them.

Comment: I hope "photon cannons" could be used as a formal jargon in some spectroscopy papers.

Comment: @MaudPieTheRocktorate well, there does exist an [electron gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_gun) (which in Russian is called an "electron cannon"), so I suppose it's quite possible for a photon cannon to exist :)

Comment: For photons, it is usually guns - single photon guns.